# How to understand PHP syntax when it's explained "in theory" on php.net?

Tags: php

I'm reading php.net in order to get acquainted with new functions. I'm very newbie in learning any programming language, and when I read how any function's syntax is explained, it's not easy for me.
ie: **array_unshift()**
I get this:

```
int array_unshift(array array, mixed variable [,mixed variable...])
```

I read some examples, but I can't understand ***a priori*** [ed note: not having any prior knowledge] how the syntax works reading only the theoretical explanation. I haven't found any other question related to this.

Comment: The 1st param is the array you want to modify then you pass in as many values/variables as you want to prepend to the array.  It returns the new length.  It's explained pretty well I think.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But why it says "int" at the beggining? I don´t belive is from "integer"...

Comment: Maybe because english isn't your native language? Anyways, if you scroll a bit down, the parameters are all explained including the return value. Also check the examples out.

Comment: `int` is referring to the return value, which is the "new number of elements in the array." It might help to look at the examples on php.net. Also, check the "parameters" section just below the "description". It defines the parameters that can be passed to `array_unshift()`.

Comment: @RosamundaRosamunda: The `int` before the function name is what it returns.  `int` is short for "integer".

Comment: yes, probably :) But, why is "array" repeated? I don´t think that has something to do with english language. Anyway I do understand when I read the examples, but I would like to get it just with the theoretical explanation (ie. a cheatsheet).

Comment: I think this should be migrated to `meta.php.net` ;))

Comment: @RosamundaRosamunda: AH!  The 1st `array` is the "type" of the parameter.  And the 2nd `array` should really be `$array`, the parameter name.

Comment: Array isn't repeated. The manual page actually specifies `array &$array`, which means that it is of the array type, that an example name of this variable could be `$array`, and the ampersand (`&`) means that this variable will be updated by the function.

Comment: Thanks @Sammitch, I had to google what "a priori" meant >.>

Comment: @RocketHazmat so did I... :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misquoted the function definition, it is:

```
int array_unshift ( array &$array , mixed $value1 [, mixed $... ] )
```

which equates to:

```
return_type function_name ( type_hint $arg_name , type_hint $arg_name [, type_hint $...] )
```

where `...` means it will accept as many more arguments as you want to throw at it.

Answer (score 4):

This can easily be narrowed done to the following

1. return value: `int`
2. name of the method: `array_unshift`
3. list of accepted arguments:

   1. first argument:

      - type: `array`
      - name that will be used in the description, etc.: `array`
   2. second argument:

      - type: `mixed` (multiple types possible)
      - name that will be used in the description, etc.: `variable`

You can read more about the types in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/language.types.php).

Answer (score 2):

If you understand by example, like you've said, you can always:

```
php --rf array_unshift

Function [ <internal:standard> function array_unshift ] {

  - Parameters [3] {
    Parameter #0 [ <required> &$stack ]
    Parameter #1 [ <required> $var ]
    Parameter #2 [ <optional> $... ]
  }
}
```

But really, all of this is explained in manual, you just need to learn what to search.